# Count the number of occurrences of a special symbol

Tags: c#, .net

I want to count the WMC for a program. For this am counting the no. of "void", "return", "main", "set" and "get" between 2 " { " and " } " symbols, because they indicate the begin n end of a class. Am using the following code:-

```
namespace ConsoleApplication27
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cflag=0,mflag=0;
        string var1 = File.ReadAllText(@"c:\\Users\\kinnu\\My Documents\\program.txt");
        string[] words = var1.Split(' ');
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            if (word == "{")
                cflag++;
            if (word == "}")
                cflag--;
            if (word == "Main")
                mflag++;
            if (word == "void")
                mflag++;
            if (word == "return")
                mflag++;
            if (word == "set")
                mflag++;
            if (word == "get")
                mflag++;
            if (cflag == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("The number of methods are:" + mflag);
        }
    }
}
```

}

The problem is its identifying thw words but not " { " and " } " symbols. I have tried displayin no. of methods right after decrementing the cflag variable but of no use

Please help!!!!

Comment: Can you show us a sample from the file?

Comment: You aren't taking into consideration that the braces ('{' and '}') may be immediately preceded or followed by a newline.

Comment: Judging from his words, it's a C# source file

Comment: You'll need a proper parser for doing this accurately. Try running what you have here on itself and you'll see what I mean. You need to take quoted strings into account and also account for the fact that space is not a required delimiter.

Comment: @dwerner. You're right but he's splitting by space (" ") and there can be a method like `void foo{` with no space

Comment: @PinnyM - spot on - that's the answer I reckon

Comment: @gdoron - take it. Good eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this split will work better:

```
string[] words = var1.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\r', '\n', '\t' },
        StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understood that i went wrong with the splitting thing. I have now rectified it. :) Thank you....

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're running into is that `var1.Split(' ')` is splitting the string only on spaces. Since most braces end with a newline character - as opposed to a space - the collected string therefore is not a single '{' or '}' character, it is that character followed by a newline character (`'\r'` or `'\n'` or the two characters `"\r\n"`) followed by whatever starts the next line in the file. The same thing will occur with any of the other keywords you're collecting, if you care to try.

The problem is not just isolated to newline characters, however. If your source code contains punctuation or operators next to your keywords, your code as it is will not collect it currently either. Try it out: your code will not collect any keywords in `Main()`, or `(void)`, or `return(value)` or `get{return val;}` or `set{}` either.

Also, your code as it is does not care where it finds the keywords. For example, if it finds `Main` or `return` in a string literal, or inside of a comment, it will consider it to be the start of a function or the start of a return statement even though they have no effect on the actual structure of the C# program.

Your best chance of fixing these problems is to abandon `string.Split` in the first place and just iterate through individual characters, collecting keywords yourself. Even then, you will still collect unwanted keywords inside of strings and comments. If you are a perfectionist, and you want to avoid collecting these, you can find the production for the C# language syntax structure in §2 of the CSharp Specification (found in "Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio XXXX\VC#\Specifications\1033\CSharp Language Specification.doc", or "Program Files (x86)..." on 64 bit systems) but that's a bit of overkill for most cases, don't you think?

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the points you mentioned. Thanks for mentioning them. Will surely do the required rectifications. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You only split on ' '. If the file you're reading is an average source file, it also contains other kinds of whitespace you should split on. Carriage returns, line feeds, tabs.

And it's perfectly possible to have a `{` directly followed by a non-space character, so you should also check for that.

And I don't see where you check that the words are not inside a literal string.

Comment: +1I was going to say this too. Note that this is perfectly valid code that wouldn't be handled properly in any of these .Split() situations: `if(true) {x = " Main { Main "};`

Comment: Yes. I forgot to take that point into consideration. Thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 1):

Working on the assumption that your file that you are trying to parse is C# code (I am basing this assumption on the question's tags, and the fact that the keywords you are looking for look like C#).

Instead of trying to .Split() or even regular expressions (I'm surprised no one recommended that yet), which will always have some odd edge case that is not properly handled, the best thing you can do is to properly parse the code into a syntax tree.

Lucky for you, Microsoft has already done the hard work.  You can feed a C# file to the Roslyn compiler, and get back the syntax tree. That will give you pretty much the best parsing of a file you are going to find, and will give you the best, most error free results.

Additional reading:

- [Roslyn MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-en/roslyn)
- [Using Roslyn to Parse C# code files](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/20/using-roslyn-to-parse-c-code-files/)

Comment: Actually am a newbie to .net technology so don't know much about parsing techniques. But will try to study about them :)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need to use:

```
Regex r = new Regex(" +"); //specify delimiter (spaces) 
string [] words = r.Split(var1); //(convert string to array of words)  

if (word.Trim().Equals("Main")) { }
```

Comment: string class overload the `==` operator to do value equality. it won't change anything...